# Prevent my text Input from sending a null value in my chat app

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I designed the app and connected it with firebase firestore as backend, and everything works fine but then I discovered that when the send button is pressed even without having any text in the text input field so it sends a null value to my firestore database which eventuallly returns an error. Please can I get any ideas on how to fix this.
This is the code that covers the whole process

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:one_gov_fx/constants.dart';
import 'package:one_gov_fx/widgets/customAppBar.dart';

final FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
User firebaseUser;

class ChatScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = "chat_screen";

  @override
  _ChatScreenState createState() => _ChatScreenState();
}

class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  String messageText;
  final messageTextController = TextEditingController();
  bool isMe;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUser();
  }

  void getCurrentUser() async {
    try {
      final user = _auth.currentUser;
      if (user != null) {
        firebaseUser = user;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

//  void getMessage() async{
//    final messages = await _firestore.collection('messages').getDocuments();
//    for( var message in messages.documents){
//      print(message.data);
//    }
//  }

//  void messageStream() async {
//    await for (var snapshot in _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots()) {
//      for (var message in snapshot.documents) {
//        print(message.data);
//      }
//    }
//  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: CustomAppBar(
        title: Text('Traders Room'),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            MessageStreamWidget(),
            Container(
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                      child: TextField(
                        textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences,
                        maxLines: null,
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.newline,
                        controller: messageTextController,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          messageText = value;
                          //Do something with the user input.
                        },
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(
                                Radius.circular(38),
                              ),
                            ),
                            hintText: 'Type your message here. Be Nice...!!!'),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
                    child: IconButton(
                      color: kPrimaryColor,
                      icon: Icon(Icons.send),
                      onPressed: () {
                        messageTextController.clear();
                        _firestore.collection('messages').doc().set({
                          'author': firebaseUser.photoURL,
                          'sender': firebaseUser.displayName,
                          'text': messageText,
                          'timestamp':
                              DateTime.now().toUtc().millisecondsSinceEpoch
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MessageStreamWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('messages')
          .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
          .snapshots(),
      //Async Snapshot
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              backgroundColor: kPrimaryColor,
            ),
          );
        }
        final messages = snapshot.data.docs;
        List<TextBubble> messageWidgets = [];
        for (var message in messages) {
          final messageText = message.data()['text'];
          final messageSender = message.data()['sender'];

          final currentUser = firebaseUser.displayName;

          final messageWidget = TextBubble(
              sender: messageSender,
              text: messageText,
              isMe: currentUser == messageSender);
          messageWidgets.add(messageWidget);
        }
        return Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            reverse: true,
            children: messageWidgets,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class TextBubble extends StatelessWidget {
  final String sender;
  final String text;
  final bool isMe;

  TextBubble({this.sender, this.text, this.isMe});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment:
            isMe ? CrossAxisAlignment.end : CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(
            sender,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 11),
          ),
          Material(
              borderRadius: isMe
                  ? BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(10))
                  : BorderRadius.only(
                      topRight: Radius.circular(10),
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(10)),
              elevation: 5,
              color: isMe ? kPrimaryColor : Colors.white,
              child: Padding(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
                child: Text(
                  text,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: isMe ? Colors.white : Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
                ),
              )),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either disable the button when there is no message, or just do nothing inside the function instead. To disable a button, pass null instead of function.

Method 1 - passing null:

```
Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
    child: IconButton(
        color: kPrimaryColor,
        icon: Icon(Icons.send),
        // don't pass press callback when text is empty
        onPressed: messageText.isEmpty ? null : () {
            messageTextController.clear();
            _firestore.collection('messages').doc().set({
                'author': firebaseUser.photoURL,
                'sender': firebaseUser.displayName,
                'text': messageText,
                'timestamp':
                    DateTime.now().toUtc().millisecondsSinceEpoch
            });
        },
    ),
),
```

Method 2 - returning early:

```
Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 5),
    child: IconButton(
        color: kPrimaryColor,
        icon: Icon(Icons.send),
        onPressed: () {
            // return early if text is empty
            if (messageText.isEmpty) return;
            messageTextController.clear();
            _firestore.collection('messages').doc().set({
                'author': firebaseUser.photoURL,
                'sender': firebaseUser.displayName,
                'text': messageText,
                'timestamp':
                        DateTime.now().toUtc().millisecondsSinceEpoch
            });
        },
    ),
),
```